# c# new line printing out a String

Tags: c#, string, printing

How Can i Print out the whole String ?
I want to know how i can do a New Line printing out this String ?

Thank you for the Answer

```
    private void drucken_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
        printDialog.Document = printDocument;

        printDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler (PrintReceiptPage);

        DialogResult result = printDialog.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument.Print();
        }           
    }

    private void PrintReceiptPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        string message = "Haalloodhsak dfsdfsfdsfsdfdssdddddddddddddddsf  Tetsn dfgdfgdfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdfggdfdfg gdgdgdffgddfgdfgdfggdf dfgdfgdfgdfggdf";
        int y;
        // Print receipt
        Font myFont = new Font("Times New Roman", 15, FontStyle.Bold);
         y = e.MarginBounds.Y;
       e.Graphics.DrawString(message , myFont, Brushes.Red,   e.MarginBounds.X, y);
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# How to print a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940323/c-sharp-how-to-print-a-string)

Comment: I'm sure you mean you want it wrapped to the width of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your PrintReceiptPage method to something like this:

```
private void PrintReceiptPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    string message = "Haalloodhsak dfsdfsfdsfsdfdssdddddddddddddddsf  Tetsn dfgdfgdfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdfggdfdfg gdgdgdffgddfgdfgdfggdf dfgdfgdfgdfggdf";
    int yMargin;
    // Print receipt
    Font myFont = new Font("Times New Roman", 15, FontStyle.Bold);
    yMargin = e.MarginBounds.Y;

    // Create rectangle for drawing. 
    float x = 150.0F;
    float y = 150.0F;
    float width = 200.0F;
    float height = 50.0F;
    RectangleF drawRect = new RectangleF(x, yMargin, width, height);

    e.Graphics.DrawString(message, myFont, Brushes.Red, drawRect);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to wrap the text automatically. One thing you could do is to measure a part of the string, and add characters if there is enough space. If there is not enough space, print and move down a bit.

To measure a string, use `e.Graphics.MeasureString(string,Font)`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually there is a way to wrap it automatically: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21kdfbzs(v=vs.110).aspx